# Retrieving null values from List items using OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, list, onitemclicklistener

Ok so I've been trying to get an OnItemClickListener to retrieve values from list items. At the moment the click is being registered but the values aren't coming through. Here're the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class DiarySchedule extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private DiaryDataSource datasource;
    private static final String TAG = "MAD Diary Schedule";
    private String delTitle;
    private String delDate;
    private String delTime;
    private String editTitle;
    private String editDate;
    private String editTime;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diary_schedule);

    datasource = new DiaryDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<DiaryEntry> values = datasource.getAllDiaryEntries();

    DiaryScheduleAdapter adapter = new DiaryScheduleAdapter(this,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());


}


public class DiaryScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DiaryEntry>
{
    private LayoutInflater li;

    public DiaryScheduleAdapter(Context context, List<DiaryEntry> values) 
    {
        super(context, 0, values);
        li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        DiaryEntry diaryEntry = getItem(position);

        View v = convertView;
        if ( v == null ) 
        {
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.diary_schedule, null);
        }

        TextView date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListDate);
        String initialDate = diaryEntry.getDate();
        String formattedDate = ConvertToDate(initialDate);
        date.setText(formattedDate);

        TextView link = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListLink);
        link.setText(" at ");

        TextView time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTime);
        time.setText(diaryEntry.getTime());

        TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle);
        title.setText(diaryEntry.getTitle());

        v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

        return v;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
{
    new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.diary_menu, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.add:
            Intent intent = new Intent(DiarySchedule.this, DiaryAddEntry.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.diary_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.edit:
            Intent editIntent = new Intent(DiarySchedule.this, DiaryEditEntry.class);

            editTitle = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle)).getText();
            editDate = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListDate)).getText();
            editDate = GetInfoConvertToDate(editDate);
            editTime = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTime)).getText();

            editIntent.putExtra("title", editTitle);
            editIntent.putExtra("date", editDate);
            editIntent.putExtra("time", editTime);

            startActivity(editIntent);
            break;

        case R.id.delete:
            delTitle = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle)).getText();
            delDate = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListDate)).getText();
            delDate = GetInfoConvertToDate(delDate);
            delTime = (String) ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTime)).getText();

            Log.v(TAG, "Hopefully title is: " + delTitle + " with date of " + delDate + " and time of " + delTime);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}



DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        switch (which)
        {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            datasource.deleteDiaryEntry(delTitle, delDate, delTime);

            // IN CASE NEED TO DELETE ALL DB ENTRIES UNCOMMENT THIS 
            // (AND COMMENT THE ABOVE METHOD)
            //datasource.deleteAll();

            Intent intent = new Intent(DiarySchedule.this, DiarySchedule.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            // No action taken
            break;
        }
    }
};



@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener
{           
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position)
    {
            mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "onItemClick at position" + mPosition); 
        final String title = (String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle)).getText();
        System.out.println("Title is: " + title);
        String date = (String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListDate)).getText();
        date = GetInfoConvertToDate(date);
        System.out.println("Date is: " + date);
        final String time = (String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTime)).getText();
        System.out.println("Time is: " + time);

        Intent descIntent = new Intent(DiarySchedule.this, DiaryDetailed.class);

        descIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        descIntent.putExtra("date", date);
        descIntent.putExtra("time", time);

        startActivity(descIntent);
    }               
}

}
```

When debugging it reaches the OnItemClickListener OnClick method, go through it properly but just doesn't pick up the values, which come out empty. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Problem solved - thanks to everyone who posted a suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having multiple views with the same id (one on each row). When getting the value try replacing

```
final String title = (String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle)).getText();
```

with

```
final String title = (String) ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle)).getText();
```

Same thing for the other values you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks azertiti - this was the thing I was missing to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

You are very much over-complicating things

in your main DiarySchedule activity you should implement OnItemClickListener.
Override the onItemClick method for the listener and perform your actions in there.
Set your listener by calling getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); in your onCreate method..

Ex.

```
public class DiarySchedule extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener
{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diary_schedule);

    datasource = new DiaryDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<DiaryEntry> values = datasource.getAllDiaryEntries();

    DiaryScheduleAdapter adapter = new DiaryScheduleAdapter(this,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); //this sets the listener


   }
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
   {

      String title = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTitle)).getText().toString();
      String date = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListDate)).getText().toString();
      date = GetInfoConvertToDate(date);
      String time = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.scheduleListTime)).getText().toString();


      Intent descIntent = new Intent(DiarySchedule.this, DiaryDetailed.class);
      descIntent.putExtra("title", title);
      descIntent.putExtra("date", date);
      descIntent.putExtra("time", time);

      startActivity(descIntent);

   }

}
```

You can then remove the call to v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position)); in your adapter and the class that you created to handle clicks.

When in the onItemClick method and you are trying to use "findViewById" you should be using "v.findViewById(id);" since you are searching within the View "v".

This is likely your problem to begin with. (and you can fix it as such) but i'd recommend doing it the "proper" way as I describe above instead of having individual handlers for each item in your listview

Comment: Thanks dymmeh! I'll definitely be coming back and looking to sharpen up all my code with tips like this, but as I'm on a strict time limit for now I'm just getting things working. Cheers!

Comment: Well, this will take you 2 minutes to do. Copy what I have above, take your corrected code with "v.findViewById" from your onclick, paste it into the onItemClick above.. change mPosition to position, done. :)  Less + cleaner code, less classes, less overhead associated with having individual click listeners for each view. well worth the small amount of time it takes to change

Comment: i updated the source to include the changes you should make. now you have 0 excuse for not implementing it ;)